# How to make rest API that responds to post(data=data,header=header) with python and flask

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I am trying to make a rest API in `python.flask` and I want it to be responsive to `python.requests.post(data=data,header=header)`. But every tutorial and website only shows me Postman and
An API that responds to `python.requests.post(PARAMS=data,header=header)` but `"PARAMS"` does not work for my case. I've tried using `python.flask.request.get_json()`, I've tried using `python.flask.Resource`, I've tried using another one here:-

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from json import loads as dictionary
from flask import request as req
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def post(username,token,url):
    # gotit=dictionary(gotit)
    k = '{"name":'+username+',"password":'+token+',"link":'+url+'}'
    print(k)
    return k
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()#debug=True)
```

But all in vain. Please help me make an API that responds to this:- `python.requests.post(data=data,header=header)`. And also help with the header thing.

> Python.v3.8

Comment: Also, I don't want to use Postman at all

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code but with some modification:

Server Code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    # you will get that data in request.data you can simplify/jsonfiy
    text = str(request.data)
    t = request.data
    return t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`python.requests` Code:

```
import requests

header = {
    "Content-Type":"text/plain"
}

data = {
    "username":"myName",
    "password":"myPass",
    "url":"myWeb"
}
d = requests.post(url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', data=data, headers=header)
# 
print(d.content)
```

Response from server something like this:
[response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqdP3.png)

> I'm Using Python 3.9.1

*Hope it will help You:)*

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Comment: I could not find a proper linkparams to the dictionary function so I made my own:-


def dictionary(a):
 x = a.split("&")
 b = []
 for i in x:
  b.append(i.split("="))
 c = {}
 for j in b:
  if j[1][0] == "{":
   c[str(j[0])] = json.loads(str(j[1]).replace("'", '"'))
  else:
   c[str(j[0])] = str(j[1])

 print(c)
 return c

Comment: @Ninjago77 Well Done!